# Amazon music on a NAS - shared state between computers

Tags: windows-10, nas, music-management

I have a couple of computers at home.  I use Amazon Music app on Windows 10 to download my music to a `NAS` drive.

If I download from one computer to the NAS, when I use the other computer it doesn't know that that file has been downloaded - even though both point at the NAS as the download location.

Is it possible to copy or share the settings between the devices - so I don't have to keep downloading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can.  Mine sync'd by setting the download location then in the advanced tab, clicking on the Reload button.  This can be done by clicking on you user name drop down and selecting settings.

NOTE: I am using version 5.5.1.1028 of Amazon Music Player.

## Goto Settings

Click on the user and select settings.

[image: User]

## Select download location

For this you need to map a network drive to the `NAS`.  I am sure this used to work in the previous version of the Amazon Music Player - where you could just type in the path - now it is read only.  Given I haven't setup my Network at home, the computers didn't show up for me under the Network item when browsing.

[image: Settings]

## Reload music information

Click on the **Start Reload** button.

[image: Reload]

## Sync'd

Now what is downloaded already should have the correct icon.

[image: Syncd]